# Cleaning the data that has random 0s and a space in front of my data, but inconsistently spread across the dataframe

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Say if I have a dataset that looks like this:

Lets call this dataframe as DF1, and each column is labeled as a character string

| Patients | Gene 1 | Gene 2 | Gene 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1223 | 0 0.2412 | 1.125 |
| B | 1.025 | 0.9011 | 0 0.1242 |
| C | 0 0.1242 | 1.542 | 0 0.1224 |

What is the most efficient way to remove the random 0s that are in front of the dataframe, then converting each to become a numeric value such that it looks like this below?

| Patients | Gene 1 | Gene 2 | Gene 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1223 | 0.2412 | 1.125 |
| B | 1.025 | 0.9011 | 0.1242 |
| C | 0.1242 | 1.542 | 0.1224 |

I looked online, and I saw that we can use as.numeric(unlist()), but I still seem to have the error due to the leading 0 with the awkward space. I suspect that I get an error of **object cannot be coerced to type ‘double’** because I didnt clean these random numbers out?

Any help on cleaning this data into the desired data, and into a numeric set would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop `across` the 'Gene' columns, remove the 0 followed by one or more spaces that precedes a digit (`(?=\\d)`) and convert to `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("Gene"), 
        ~ as.numeric(str_remove(., ".*0\\s+(?=[0-9.]+$)"))))
```

-output

```
df1
Patients  Gene1  Gene2  Gene3
1        A 0.1223 0.2412 1.1250
2        B 1.0250 0.9011 0.1242
3        C 0.1242 1.5420 0.1224
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Patients = c("A", "B", "C"), Gene1 = c("0.1223", 
"1.025", "0 0.1242"), Gene2 = c("0 0.2412", "0.9011", "1.542"
), Gene3 = c("1.125", "0 0.1242", "0 0.1224")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That was helpful thank you! Say if I were to have a long data set, that has hundreds of columns with vastly different names for the genes. What can I add in the starts_with() parentheses to account for all differently named columns without having to type every name out?

Comment: If it is excluding the first column, use `across(-1, ~ as.numeric(...`

Comment: thank you! That worked! I think I got a warning that says: NAs introduced by coercion. Is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: @Bbkazu there may be other cases in addition to the pattern you showed, which may have coercces to NA by `as.numeric`

Comment: Ohhh I see! I think I noticed some data even had a 0 0 0.231 in front of it. So like two 0s in front. Can I do a OR command inside the str_remove() to apply for any that has a 0 0 as well? What would you recommend for these situations where there is a 0 0.212 ;  0 0 0.213 ; and regular 0.1221 values?

Comment: In that case we can just add `".*0\\s+(?=\\d)"` as pattern

Comment: Oh thank you! Like this?
~ as.numeric(str_remove(., "0\\s+(?=\\d)", ".*0\\s+(?=\\d)"))))

Comment: I meant only to replace the old pattern with new one.  I updatd the post.  Please check

Comment: I changed the pattern and tested with `df1$Gene1[2] <- "0 0 0 1.025"`.  It is working now

Comment: Thank you! This would also remove all of the 0 0.121 examples as well right?

Comment: @Bbkazu Yes, the `.*` will match all characters before the condition